# Dirichlet problem for Laplace equation in triangular grid

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I need to find the solution in rectangle on an unstructured triangular grid, the example of grid
[here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljsFK.png)

I should estimate the values of function for the vertices of triangles. Five point discretization will not fit these requirements, but I can't find any papers about the discretization on unstructured grids. Is there any existing approach for this problem?

Comment: I don't see any reason you can't use finite elements on these grids, at least the grid you shown wouldn't have any problem with a FE solution.

Comment: The usual approach is using finite element method. You can implement it yourself or pick some finite element software package (like FEniCS, for example) that simplifies conversion between week formulation of the problem and its numerical discretization.

However, you are not restricted to use FEM in this case. You still can use finite differences and unknown coefficients method to derive the approximation in each point of the grid (if I remember correctly, you need 5 neighbors for the first order approximation and 7 neighbors for the second order).

Comment: @uranix Thank you for the advice, I successfully applied FEM to this problem using sk-fem Python library!